# red alert notify top of div like facebook stackexchange

Tags: jquery, css

when i recieve comment in facebook OR answer of my question StackExchange i see red Circle in top left with any effect . i load/refresh my div every X minutes. now i need to print my result ( 1,2,3 ...) in this ***red Circle*** . how to work this? my result in `DIV id="new"`.

My Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#new').load('new.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
</script>

<div id="new"></div>
```

demo Screen :

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the SetTimeOut() javascript function

```
(function(){
        $.ajax({
            'url': 'news.php', 
            'success':  function (data,textStatus)
                        {
                            var res = $.parseJSON(data);
                            if(res.ok)
                            {
                                $('#news').html(res.newsCount);
                            }
                        }
        });
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
    })();​
```

i don't know what your new.php does, but i think an ajax function is a better way to get the new notifications count

in exemple : 
http://jsfiddle.net/PCSL5/3/

for the php :

```
$result = array();
$result['ok'] = false;
/*
* make here your DB Query
*/

if($queryResultAsCount > 0 )
{
    $result['newsCount'] = $queryResultAsCount;
    $result['ok'] = true;
}

$json = json_encode($result);

die($json);
```

On your ajax request, you get an JSON objet which got 2 attributes res.ok & res.newsCount (as the php table you die)

Comment: Please read the question carefully. I made ​​the red circle by CSS and Jquery effect.

Comment: make the circle yes, but you have to get the text (i.e. (1) ) from your database ?!

Comment: Sure, i gain question : now i need to print **my result** ( 1,2,3 ...) in circle. only red circle my question!!

Comment: $('#new').html(x); ? As the jsfiddle?

Comment: thanks. for your function i put what's code in news.php ? what's `res.ok` ?

Comment: In your news.php, you have to put a piece of php code who return you the count of news notification as Json. i'll try to let you an exemple on the post

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10543/discussion-between-bbking-and-mr-deleted)